# Obtaining webpage network requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

Is it possible to obtain network requests of a webpage without using the Selenium package? By network requests I am referring to the output of the network tab in various browser's devtools views.

Answer (score 0):

It depends which "network requests" you need, some can be easily parsed from the html.
For example a page containing the line:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/mypage.css">
```

Will have a `mypage.css` request somewhere in it's network tab.

But many "network requests" are made from javascript, and you will Selenium or something like it to get them.

A good way to know exactly what requires javascript is to open the page in your browser with javascript disabled and look at the (usually much shorter) network tab.

Comment: Thanks, I'm afraid what I am looking for is a request made via js. Looks like Selenium may be the only option here.